# Python reading a Json data stopped working

Tags: python, json

I was using this piece of code from [datahub](https://datahub.io/core/population#python)

This was the code actually,

```
from datapackage import Package

package = Package('http://datahub.io/core/population/datapackage.json')

# get list of resources:
resources = package.descriptor['resources']
resourceList = [resources[x]['name'] for x in range(0, len(resources))]

data = package.resources[0].read()
print(data)
```

This was the data getting returned -

```
Country Name,Country Code,Year,Value
Arab World,ARB,1960,92490932
Arab World,ARB,1961,95044497
Arab World,ARB,1962,97682294
Arab World,ARB,1963,100411076
Arab World,ARB,1964,103239902
```

Now, this line

> data = package.resources[0].read()

stopped working. This was the error - Methods iter/read are not supported for non tabular data

Then I was loading them inside a table in SQL,

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    Val1 = data[i][0]
    Val2= data[i][1]
    Val3= data[i][2]
    Val4= data[i][3]
    cursor.execute("insert into Population_Country (CountryName,CountryCode,Year,PopulationNumber) values (?,?,?,?)", Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4)
    cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Do you have `pandas`?

Comment: Yes, I do have pandas. But if you are referring to the codes in this one - https://datahub.io/core/population#pandas. I don't know how to get the data as I required(Similar output like data in question)

Comment: I used `requests` and found that this package loads data in two steps. First, the metadata, reads the path to the ACTUAL data (which is https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/population/population/data/c8df6fc75bdf8cbdb0052140b7eeba7f/population.csv among others), and then reads _that_.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ So where is the code going wrong, If you have got an working code - Can you post that as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how it was earlier but if you take a look on what resources are inside:

```
['validation_report', 'population_csv', 'population_csv_preview', 'population_json', 'population_zip', 'population']
```

So `0` report is `'validation_report'` with next descriptor:

```
{'bytes': 598, 'datahub': {'type': 'derived/report'}, 'description': 'Validation report for tabular data', 'dpp:streamedFrom': 'validation_report.json', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'format': 'json', 'name': 'validation_report', 'path': 'https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/population/validation_report/data/b6445474af133352488c54ed6c6fd6f2/validation_report.json', 'profile': 'data-resource'}
```

And it's not tabular so it cannot be read using `read()`.
As I understand you need `"population_csv"` resource so I would take it like this:

```
package.get_resource("population_csv").read()
```